# PostExcute custom dialogue image not changing?

Tags: java, android

For some reason this isn't working with a dialog. I've used the showImage method loads of time before in this app via postExecute and its worked fine. However its not showing the image it should when doing it this way. Am I missing something? At the moment I've just got the image URL hardcoded to test, but later it will be passed to this method from doInBackground.

```
protected void onPostExecute() {        

    Dialog liveView = new Dialog(myView.this, R.style.Dialog);
    liveView.setContentView(R.layout.liveview_dialogue);
    TextView title = (TextView)liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewTitle);           
        Button button = (Button) liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewButton);
        ImageView imgDisplay= (ImageView)liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewImage);
        showImage("http://mytest.com/test.jpg", imgDisplay);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        liveView.show();
        dialog.cancel(); //used to cancel the previous progress dialog. 

}
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/liveViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Tracking"
     />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/liveViewImage"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/liveViewButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:text="OK" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Dialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Show image method:

```
 public void showImage(String url, ImageView passed){
        int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher; 
        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(url, loader, passed);
    }
```

ImageLoader.class: http://pastebin.com/Z2BvvzXk

MemoryCache.class: http://pastebin.com/bJUwPs45

FileCache.class: http://pastebin.com/0XHBawd0

Utils.class: http://pastebin.com/KXbXRVC2

Comment: I'd be willing to be that the answer lies within the showImage method, but you didn't include that code

Comment: I've said that I've used this method a lot elsewhere in the app and its fine.

Comment: So, a method will always work the same way in every context you call it from, unaffected by external variables and ways in which it is called?  My methods don't, so I doubt I can help you.

Comment: Fair point, it really has to be something to do with the context of how I'm calling it as thats the only thing thats changed. I've updated my post with the showImage code, although it calls another class but it may be enough.

Comment: That's not where the work is done.  But, btw "ImageView image = passed;" is redundant and does the same thing as passing the method arg directly into the DisplayImage method.  Is that ImageLoader class from an external library?  That's where the work is done, so that's where your answer probably is.  I imagine that the DisplayImage method is wrapping your ImageView reference in a listener that executes when the image download is complete.  That might be where the break down occurs.

Comment: Thanks Rich, I've removed those lines. I've also edited the post to included pastebin links to the external classes that do the work.

Comment: Is "http://mytest.com/test.jpg" a placeholder url or a link to an actual image.  Because I get a 302 Not Found response, and that could be your answer right there.

Comment: It was just a short url I was using for this post. I'm actually using a real url on my test.